# Fill certain range in a Fortran array with implied loop

Tags: arrays, loops, fortran

I want to fill an array with some values from an implied loop... my problem is that, while the first line works fine, the second gets the error from my in-editor debugger **'Expected right paranthesis in expression'**.

```
usum(:,:,:,1:3) = (usum(:,:,:,ll)+(um(ll)*ur(:,:,:,ll),ll=1,3)
usum(:,:,:,4:6) = (usum(:,:,:,ll+3)+(um(ll)*ur(:,:,:,ll))**2, ll=1,3)
```

I don't see why the first line works, while the second doesn't...

It's fixed formatted source code and the exact error message from ifort is:

```
snapstat.f(353): error #5082: Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...         
     1                  ll=1,3)                                                                                                                              
--------------------------^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
snapstat.f(355): error #5082: Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...         
     1                  ur(:,:,:,ll))**2, ll=1,3)
--------------------------------------------^
snapstat.f(353): error #5082: Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...         
     1                  ll=1,3)                                                                                                                              
--------------------------^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
snapstat.f(355): error #5082: Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...         
     1                  ur(:,:,:,ll))**2, ll=1,3)
--------------------------------------------^
```

(I split the line in my editor, so it's not longer than 72)

Comment: Fixed or free formatted source code? Also show the exact error message.

Comment: Now the error message is about `Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...         ` and the question states `Expected right paranthesis in expression`. Please explain.

Comment: Yes, first I got the error message from my in-editor debugger, when you asked for it, I checked for the compiler error message.

Comment: Comment and answer are based on code we have, if this is incorrect, please supply the details. Read  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EteleB AFAIK, the implied loop cannot be used for such assignments (please correct me if it can...), so it is probably best to just use a simple do-loop overl `ll` (to evaluate the two lines for each `ll`). Btw, gfortran-8 gives "Expected a right parenthesis in expression at ..." for a similar error (even for free form).

Comment: @roygvib, you are correct: an array constructor would be required as a similar RHS.

Comment: thanks @roygvib, finally I did write a simple do-loop

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, I think the implied loop cannot be used directly for this kind of summation. For example, the following code tries to sum `p(:,:,k) * c(k)` over `k = 1,4`.

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: p(2,3,4), c(4), ans(2,3), k
    p = 1; c = 1

    ans(:,:) = ( p(:,:,k) + c(k), k = 1,4 )

    print *, "ans = ", ans
end
```

But gfortran gives

```
    ans(:,:) = ( p(:,:,k) + c(k), k = 1,4 )
                                1
Error: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

and Intel Fortran gives

```
test1.f90(7): error #5082: Syntax error, found '=' when expecting one of: .EQV. .NEQV. .XOR. .OR. .AND. .LT. < .LE. <= .EQ. == .NE. /= .GT. > ...
    ans(:,:) = ( p(:,:,k) + c(k), k = 1,4 )
------------------------------------^
```

So, I think it is probably best to use an explicit do-loop over `k=1,4`. (I've tried writing some one-liners, but they seem less readable...)

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: p(2,3,4), c(4), ans1(2,3), ans2(2,3), ans3(2,3), k

    !! Dummy data.
    c = [ 1, 10, 100, 1000 ]
    do k = 1, 4
        p(1,:,k) =  k
        p(2,:,k) = -k
    enddo

    ans1 = 0
    do k = 1, 4
        ans1 = ans1 + p(:,:,k) * c(k)
    enddo

    ans2 = sum( reshape( [( p(:,:,k) * c(k), k=1,4 )], shape(p) ), dim=3 )

    ans3 = sum( p * reshape( spread( c, 1, 2*3 ), shape(p) ), dim=3 )

    print *, "ans1 = ", ans1
    print *, "ans2 = ", ans2
    print *, "ans3 = ", ans3
end
```